# Mac os x; fast text editor for RTF format with colors and change background

Tags: macos, text-editor

I am llokig, for programming, a simple text editor, but wiuth the following requirements:

1- must be ultrafast to start
2- can use RTF format or some other else so I can color text easily, with a pane on screen where i select colors
3- it is possible to easily change the bacjground color

thanks

Comment: For writing code, or some more limited task related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextMate? I don't use it myself (it's not free) and I'm not sure about the "ultra fast" startup time, but I believe that it can work with RTF. http://macromates.com/

Answer (score 0):

Stickies is the best RTF editor I've found. I wish there was something a little more powerful that will handle multiple open documents a little better.